# Switching using FET

Tags: mosfet, switching, fet

I need a FET/MOSFET that would trigger switching at 0 - 5v. A voltage of 1V will be supplied to gate. What FET/MOSFET could I use? A specific FET. This is for our thesis and this is the only part I need for it to be functional. Please help :( I tried all other FETs I know but all are for 10V plus.

Comment: Are you looking for a MOSFET which must be switched 'hard' on with only 1V at its gate? If so then that's a tall order.

Answer (score 2):

Go to digikey.com. Select Product Index, Discrete Semiconductors, FETs - Single, MOSFET N-channel Metal Oxide.

Then look over to the right, and you will see that you can select by gate threshold voltage. There are hundreds with a threshold 1 volt or lower. For instance, selecting 1 volt @ 1 ma gives 107 choices, with voltages to 60 volts.

There ought to be something you can use.